# how to send a mail through java program

Tags: java

hii
I have vCard file and want to send vCard as mail to email ID
how can i send this through java program
I am using Java Eclipse IDE
on mac os x

Answer (score 2):

[JavaMail API](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/).

Download JavaMail API from the Downloads page from the previous link. It doesn't make a difference if you are on Mac or Windows, Java is platform independent language.

[Examples on how to use JavaMail](http://docs.sun.com/source/819-0079/dgmail.html)

Comment: thanks for suggestion.
how can i use javaMail API with Mac os

Comment: is there any difference between JavaMail API and Javax.mail?

Comment: javax.mail is the package of the JavaMail API, im updatign my answer to include your first comment

Comment: Properties props = session.getProperties();
props.put("mail.from", "user2@mailserver.com");



whats these two line means?

Comment: can u explain me plz
If I want send mail through gmail to another 
then which SMPT host i have to write 
for gmail or for another

same  for port no.